# Calculate n dates of next x days of the week

Tags: php, datetime

so I'm trying to build a function that allows me to calculate the dates of the next x days of the week, for example, I want 5 dates from now (02/08/2022), of Tuesday and Thursday, so the output should be:

```
 02/08/2022 - Tu
 02/10/2022 - Th
 02/15/2022 - Tu
 02/17/2022 - Th
 02/22/2022 - Tu
```

I'm not sure how to achieve that, since I want to be able to input various days of the week... Is there a way to do this? My current aproach is this one, but of couse, is not doing what I want, I kinda blocked right now, sorry if the answer is too obvious:

```
function getNextDates($start_date, $range_weeks, $how_many_dates, $days)
{

    $range = 'P' . ($range_weeks * 7) . 'D';
    $sd = new DateTimeImmutable($start_date);
    $nd = new DateTime($start_date);
    $dates_list = array();
    $dates_list[0] = array('day' => $sd->format('D'), 'date' => $sd->format('d-m-Y'));
    $ind = 1;
    $how_many_dates--;

    while ($how_many_dates > 0) {
        // This in case I want a n weeks space 
        $nd->add(new DateInterval($range));

        for ($i = 0; $i < count($days); $i++) {
            if (($i + 1) < count($days)) {
                if ($sd->modify($this->nextDay($days[$i])) < $sd->modify($this->nextDay($days[$i + 1]))) {
                    $nextDate = $nd->modify($this->nextDay($days[$i]));
                    $dates_list[$ind] = array('day' => $nextDate->format('D'), 'date' => $nextDate->format('d-m-Y'));
                    $how_many_dates--;
                    $ind++;
                }
            } else {
                $nextDate = $nd->modify($this->nextDay($days[$i]));
                //   $sd = $nextDate;
                $dates_list[$ind] = array('day' => $nextDate->format('D'), 'date' => $nextDate->format('d-m-Y'));
                $how_many_dates--;
                $ind++;
            }
            if ($how_many_dates <= 0) break;
        }
    }

    return $dates_list;
}
```

Being:

```
$start_date: 02/08/2022
$range_weeks: 0 // Meaning every week
$how_many_dates: 5
$days: Tuesday, Thursday
```

I got:

```
02/08/2022
02/10/2022
02/17/2022
02/24/2022
03/03/2022
```

Sorry for my amateur code...

Comment: Yes there will be a way. Have you attempted anything, even thought of a basic algorithm, or researched the date and time functions in php? We're happy to help people here if they make a good effort. We're usually less happy about starting from scratch, although if someone has done this exact thing before they may have an instant solution for you.

Comment: Hello! Thanks for the comment, I actually updated the question with my current aproach, sorry for the initial lack of details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Starting from the start date, a day is always added and it is checked whether it is the desired day of the week.

```
$start = "02/08/2022";
$number = 5;
$weekDays = ['Tue','Thu'];

$dates = [];
for($date = date_create($start); $number > 0; $date->modify('+1 Day')){
  $day = $date->format('D');
  if(in_array($day,$weekDays)) {
    $dates[] = $date->format("d/m/Y");
    $number--;
  }
}
```

Result $dates

```
array (
  0 => "08/02/2022",
  1 => "10/02/2022",
  2 => "15/02/2022",
  3 => "17/02/2022",
  4 => "22/02/2022",
)
```

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the answer, it actually does what I was trying to achieve and its simplier that I was expecting

Comment: If your problem is solved and there are no further answers, please select the answer best suits you by clicking the tick next to the answer.
The question then no longer remains open in the system.